# Modify array in observable with rxjs, return whole object

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have observable like this:

```
currentPage: 1
items: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
pageSize: 10
totalItems: 6
totalPages: 1
```

I'm trying to modify every element in items array, and then return a whole object.

```
   getAllGifts(): Observable<PagedListDTO<GiftIdeaDTO>> {
    return this.http.get<PagedListDTO<GiftIdeaDTO>>(this.urlAPI + '/GiftIdeas/GetAll').
      pipe(
        map(x => x.items.map
          (y => ({ ...y, imageContentB64: y.imageContentB64 + 'Bob' })))
        ,
        tap(console.log)
      );
  }
```

but i only get a modified array of items, no currentPage property, page Size etc.

How can i modify items array and return whole object?

Comment: Instead of `map(x => x.items.map` please try `map(x => ({...x, items: x.items.map......})` and share feedback/observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be already familiar with the usage of [spread syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). You could also use it for the outer object before applying the `Array#map` to the `items` property.

Try the following

```js
getAllGifts(): Observable<PagedListDTO<GiftIdeaDTO>> {
  return this.http
    .get<PagedListDTO<GiftIdeaDTO>>(this.urlAPI + '/GiftIdeas/GetAll')
    .pipe(
      map(ideas => ({
        ...ideas,                          // retain properties of the outer object
        items: ideas.items.map(item => ({  // adjust the `items` property
          ...item, 
          imageContentB64: item.imageContentB64 + 'Bob' 
        }))
      })),
      tap(console.log)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `map(x =>` only accounts for `x.items` and misses the rest of the `props`.

This should fix it:

```
   getAllGifts(): Observable<PagedListDTO<GiftIdeaDTO>> {
    return this.http.get<PagedListDTO<GiftIdeaDTO>>(this.urlAPI + '/GiftIdeas/GetAll').
      pipe(
        map(x => ({...x, items: x.items.map
          (y => ({ ...y, imageContentB64: y.imageContentB64 + 'Bob' })))
        }),
        tap(console.log)
      );
  }
```

In the above code, `x` is mapped to include all props and then `items` is updated using `x.items.map`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returing them, use this:

```
getAllGifts(): Observable<PagedListDTO<GiftIdeaDTO>> {
return this.http.get<PagedListDTO<GiftIdeaDTO>>(this.urlAPI + '/GiftIdeas/GetAll').
    pipe(
        map(x => {
            return {
                ...x,
                items: x.items.map(y => ({ ...y, imageContentB64: y.imageContentB64 + 'Bob' }))
            }
        })
    )
    ,tap(console.log)
    );
}
```